# How to make a Immediately-Invoked-Func-Expression to have access to a previously defined property in javascript as soon as the object is constructed

Tags: javascript, iife

```
 var Counter = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.data = (function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    })();
};

var counter = new Counter("some name");
```

**Expected behavior:** to get printed "some name".

**Current behavior:** nothing is printed.

I'm trying to have an internal property "data" available as soon as the object is constructed. This "data" is retrieved using a function that depends on the internal property "name". However, when the immediately-invoked function expression is called looks like it can't access the `this.name` property, so I can't retrieve my data immediately after the object construction.

I can make it work by first defining an equivalent to `this` like:

```
var Counter = function(name) {
    var that = {};
    that.name = name;
    that.data = (function() {
        console.log(that.name);
    })();
    return that;
};

var counter = new Counter("some name");
```

Why does this happen? How can I make it work in an elegant way?

Comment: Your self-executing function has no `return` statement.

Comment: And why exactly don't you just use `name` or pass `name` as a parameter to the function?

Comment: According to Stoyan Stefanov in "Javascript patterns" pp 43, "this" is created and returned implicitly. Either way, it doens't make a difference when I make it return "this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`this` is notorious in JavaScript for changing in different contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). The `this` in the inner function is the global object (`window` if you run it in the browser), not the `this` object in the constructor.

There are a few different solutions depending on which version of JavaScript you are targeting:

### ECMAScript 5

You can pass the `this` value using [`apply`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```js
var Counter = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.data = (function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }).apply(this);
};

var counter = new Counter("some name");
```

### ECMAScript 6

[If you are using ES6, you can use arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which automatically bind the `this` value of the parent function:

```js
var Counter = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.data = (() => {
    console.log(this.name);
  })();
};

var counter = new Counter("some name");
```

### ECMAScript 3

Another option, similar to what you have in your question, is assigning `this` to a new variable `that`. Then you can reference `that` in the child function.

```js
var Counter = function(name) {
  var that = this;
  that.name = name;
  that.data = (function() {
    console.log(that.name);
  })();
};

var counter = new Counter("some name");
```

This was the most common solution until `apply` was introduced in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: Thanks, both "apply" and "that" methods work! However I feel like using something obscure that I don't understand. Also using some simple variable instead of "this.name" makes it work. Why does the "this.name" approach doesn't work?

Comment: @mclzc As I mentioned in my answer, `this` has a different meaning in the inner function than it does in the outer function. That's why you need to pass in the value for this with `apply` or save it in another variable like `that`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your example was the context. When using `(function(){ } )()` you use a new context, which have `this.name` different than `Counter` function name property.

You can use of arrow function to make the context to get used inside of your IIFE function.

---

**WARNING**: My soluce require `ECMA2015` aka `es6` support. An other soluce without `es6` is to use @Peter Olson answer.

[Here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) you can see the compatibility table of arrow function.

```js
const Counter = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    
    this.data = (() => {
      console.log(this.name);
    })();
};

const counter = new Counter('some name');
```

Comment: I was about to ask that, if there is a way to not use es6 features, because I'm using Google Apps Scripts, which doesn't support it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some good information above. I'm also curious if you can just assign `this.data`, and then just invoke your function immediately following?

```js
var Counter = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.data = this.name;
  console.log(this.data);
};

var counter = new Counter("some name");
```